# Can I kill flies in Happy Jump?

Tags: android, happy-jump

In Happy Jump for Android is it possible to kill or defeat the flies? If so, how can I do that without dying?

Comment: You seem to be asking about a game on Kindle Fire, a device that runs on the Android OS. In that case, you should use the android tag to indicate that you are asking about the Android version of the game.

Comment: Several sources that I found say that you can survive flies with the Shield power-up, but I don't know if it will kill them, if it can sustain multiple hits, etc.

Comment: How do I get a shield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know of to survive a direct encounter with the flies.

- Fruit boost. When you have the rainbows coming out behind you after landing on a fruit, you're safe to ram through them
- Shield / Mega Shield. These boosts give you a protective helmet, and are bought from the main screen (Select Boosts!) but they cost coins each play, and only protect you for 1 hit (Shield) or 2 hits (Mega shield)